# Input type="date"

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso pegar o valor correspondente ao ano de um `<input type="date">` e subtrair da data atual, para exibir a idade de um usuário (javascript). Porém, meu resultado sempre dá "NaN". Como resolvo? E como faço para o próprio JS pegar a data (como, por exemplo, o `date("Y")` do PHP)?

```
var data = parseInt($('input[id=nasc]').val());
var ano = 2017;
var idade = ano - data;
localStorage.setItem("diaNasc", idade);
```

Comment: Deu certo a solução?

Comment: Saiba que o input date é específico do Google Crone, outros browsers poderão não trabalhar bem com ele!

Answer (score 1):

Para trabalhar com ***data*** em [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) e converter uma ***data*** do `input` do `type="date"` utilize o `new Date` do [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) onde:

```
var dataAtual = new Date(); // retornar a data atual (Date)
```

e

```
var dataInput = new Date($("#nasc").val()); // converte o valor para Date
```

depois é só fazer a operação de subtração com o método [*getFullYear()*](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp):

```
var diferenca = dataAtual.getFullYear() - dataInput.getFullYear();
```

***Código completo:***

```js
$("#nasc").on('blur', function() {
  calcular_idade();
});

function calcular_idade() {
  if ($('#nasc').val() != '') {
    var dataInput = new Date($("#nasc").val());
    if (!isNaN(dataInput)) {
      var dataAtual = new Date();
      var diferenca = dataAtual.getFullYear() -
                      dataInput.getFullYear();
      $("#lblidade").html(diferenca);
      return true;
    }
  }
  $("#lblidade").html('Data inválida');
  return false;  
}

calcular_idade();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="nasc" id="nasc" value="1980-10-01" />
<label id="lblidade"></label>
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [JavaScript Date Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)
- [JavaScript Date Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp)

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo a resposta é sobre as duas tags, não entendi.? E outra coisa tem jQuery na pergunta.

Comment: tá certo, não tinha analisado o código dele, $('input[id=nasc]').val()); só vi a pergunta ---  exibir a idade de um usuário (javascript)